# Any way to view /System/Volumes/Data/Applications from Finder?

Tags: finder, applications, catalina

For years I've maintained a "clean" `/Applications` folder that contained only the apps that were installed with the current version of macOS, and then put most third party apps into `~/Applications`. There were always a handful of apps that just wouldn't run unless they lived in the "real" `/Applications` folder, though, so those I grudgingly left in `/Applications` but tagged to distinguish from the Apple supplied apps. (I used to tag the Apple apps as well, but SIP made that more difficult.)

Catalina has now implemented a separate read only partition for the operating system and the OS installed apps, and is doing some behind the scenes magic with firmlinks to make apps on the read only partition and apps on the user writable partition both appear to be in `/Applications`. The read only apps are really in `/System/Applications`, and Finder allows me to navigate to that folder and see only the system installed apps.

However, Finder simply refuses to display the folder `/System/Volumes/Data/Applications`, which is where the user installed apps really reside. Viewing that directory in Terminal allows me to see only the user installed apps, but if you navigate to that folder in Finder, Finder "helpfully" displays the firmlinked `/Applications` folder instead.

Is there any way to override this behavior and cause Finder to display the user installed apps only, or is there another directory that *can* be viewed in Finder that displays only the user installed apps?

Comment: What's the purpose of making this distinction? Maybe there's another way of achieving your end goal. Trying to make the OS do something contrary to its design is usually trouble.

Comment: The main purposes are to organize ~/Applications into subfolders to make it easier to find particular apps, and to more clearly identify which apps can be deleted and which are considered part of the operating system. There are many other ways of doing this, and I don't really need help finding those other ways—it'd be convenient if it were possible in the Finder to display only the contents of the user-writable "Applications" directory, though.